# capture request data in angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, post, request, client-side

Is it possible to capture the request data if it is posted to a page running angular2+? Typically, I only know of posting data to server side. But am curious to see if it is possible to post to a client side javascript directly.

Forgive me if the question is absurd. I am quite a newbie when it comes to javascript.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some example.

Comment: You can't post something to the brower, you can only post to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to send an HTTP request to an Angular2 application? That is in short *impossible*.

**Why?** The frontend is by definition a **Client** and can never process a **Request**. Here is how it works:
[image]

So if your **Web Client** (a.k.a. an Angular2 app) will ever be able to receieve requests, it needs to become a **Web Server**.
Unfortunately though, Angular2 has no web server capability.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing something.